# App crashes after reloading tableview data after NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nspredicate

`UITableView` loads data perfectly at first. when i apply `NSPredicate` on     `NSMutableDictionary` *list and table reloads the data, after that on scroll the app is crashing. I guess major problem is in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Here is my code

**ViewDidLoad**

```
NSArray *allstartingPrice = @[@100,@200,@400,@500,@300,@100,@1000,@1000,@200,@700];
NSArray *alldistanceFrom = @[@7,@9,@8,@3,@30,@35,@50,@10,@15,@25];

NSAray *startingPrice = allstartingPrice;
NSAray *distanceFrom = alldistanceFrom;

list = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[list setObject:startingPrice forKey:@"startingfrom"];
[list setObject:distanceFrom forKey:@"distance"];
```

and here is method for filtering data.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray * allKeys = [list allKeys];
    return [allKeys count];
}

- (void) sortTable{
    int match = numberOfBudget;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF <= %i", match];
    startingPrice = [allstartingPrice filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    int match2 = numberOfDistance;
    NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF <= %i", match2];
    distanceFrom = [alldistanceFrom filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate2];

    list = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [list setObject:startingPrice forKey:@"startingfrom"];
    [list setObject:distanceFrom forKey:@"distance"];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

data filters perfectly but when uitableviewscroll and reaches at the end of the table app crashes.
other methods

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{

    return 150;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FSParallaxTableViewCell *cell = (FSParallaxTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[list objectForKey:@"imagesnames"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.cellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flat_color.png"];
    cell.startingat.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
    cell.startingat.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-light" size:12];
    cell.startingat.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.startingat.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flat_color.png"];
    cell.distance.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img2];
    cell.distance.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.distance.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-light" size:9];
    cell.distance.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.distance.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    NSString *dis = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ km", [[list objectForKey:@"distance"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

**error log**

[image]

Comment: Also show the tableView methods.

Comment: is number of rows in section equals to countr of the array  which holds the value ?

Comment: Please add the tableviewDatasource method so it will understand your problem.

Comment: Your error is for array index out of bounds means you are trying to access object that not inside your array.

Comment: added please view updated question

Comment: @NDoc yes i think you are right. so what is the solution that you think!

Comment: First add these two methods `numberOfrowinsection` and `cellForRowAtIndex`, Put the whole method.

Comment: these two methods are already there

Comment: @VixHunk you added `heightForRowAtIndexPath` i want `numberOfRowAtIndex`.

Comment: numberOfRowAtIndex! i never used this one can you tell me complete method?

Comment: i have already used this method and i know problem is in it.

Comment: can you please check my question numberOfRowsInSection is already there.

Comment: anyone there to answer!

Comment: You want to predicate for both array right?\

Comment: yes exactly that is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because you have two different array, and both have different filter on it, that will cause issue, Try to use single array, that contains dictionary object like this. So change your code like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSArray *allstartingPrice = @[@100,@200,@400,@500,@300,@100,@1000,@1000,@200,@700];
    NSArray *alldistanceFrom = @[@7,@9,@8,@3,@30,@35,@50,@10,@15,@25];

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<allstartingPrice.count; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dic setValue:[allstartingPrice objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"startingfrom"];
        [dic setValue:[alldistanceFrom objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"distance"];
    }
}   

- (void) sortTable{
    //int match = numberOfBudget;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startingfrom <= %d && distance <= %d", 100, 10];
    filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (filteredArray.count > 0) {
        return filteredArray.count;
    }
    return array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *dic;
    if (filteredArray.count > 0) {
        dic = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        dic = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    FSParallaxTableViewCell *cell = (FSParallaxTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[list objectForKey:@"imagesnames"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.cellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flat_color.png"];
    cell.startingat.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
    cell.startingat.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-light" size:12];
    cell.startingat.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.startingat.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.startingat.text = [dic valueForKey:@"startingfrom"];
    UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flat_color.png"];
    cell.distance.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img2];
    cell.distance.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.distance.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-light" size:9];
    cell.distance.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.distance.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.distance.text = [dic valueForKey:@"distance"];
    return cell;
}
```